# UIWebView unable to load RSS Page

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, rss

Here is my code, it doesn't seem to work for RSS pages, but works fine for google.com (or any other plain old web page), any idea why?

```
UIWebView *wv = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 510, 1024, 230)];

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://feeds.marketwatch.com/marketwatch/topstories/"];

NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

[wv loadRequest:request];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Marketwatch RSS URL you are using in your example returns XML, not HTML.  The reason it looks like HTML when you view it in a browser is that it has an xml-stylesheet attached to it that the browser is using to render a human-readible view.  However the UIWebView component does not do the same thing.

For your purposes you'd probably want to request this XML, parse it, and use the contents in a UITableView.

Comment: I'm trying an alternative approach with NSData that doesn't seem to work either: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781713/displaying-rss-xml-data-in-webview